# Permission to certificate denied in docker container running kestrel webserver

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, permissions, lets-encrypt, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to use letsencrypt certificates with a docker container. The container is running a Asp.Net Core application exposing http and https.

To run the container on the server I did these step.
First I generated the letsencrypt certificates using docker & certbot like this:

```
mkdir -p /home/username/domain.de/letsencrypt
cd /home/username/domain.de/letsencrypt
docker run --rm -it \
-v $PWD/log/:/var/log/letsencrypt/ \
-v $PWD/etc/:/etc/letsencrypt/ \
-p 80:80 \
certbot/certbot certonly --standalone -d domain.de -d www.domain.de
```

For the Kestrel webserver, I have also configured the path within the docker container to the certificate in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Certificates": {
    "Default": {
      "Path": "etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/fullchain.pem",
      "KeyPath": "etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/privkey.pem"
    }
  }
}
```

Then start the application passing a volume with the letsencrypt certificates.

```
docker run -p 80:80 \
-p 443:443 \
-e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80 \
-e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=443 \
-v /home/username/domain.de/letsencrypt/etc:/etc/letsencrypt \
dockerhubaccount/domain.de
```

This leads to a permission denied exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
      Hosting failed to start
      System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/fullchain.pem' is denied.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
```

I had also tried wether I put the path wrong, but when changing it the error changes to path not found. So the path is correct, docker or the .Net runtime seen to be missing the permission.

What is the proper way to set the correct permission for docker to use the certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the permissions for the folder `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` fixed the permission problem.

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live/
```

But I am concerned because of [this answer from the
Letsencrypt forum](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/permission-denied-to-etc-letsencrypt-live/72892):

> You should change the permissions on the live directory back to what
> they were, e.g. with sudo chmod 700 /etc/letsencrypt/live/.
>
> Your private keys are sensitive, and it’s not supposed to be publicly
> accessible.
>
> (If the live directory is the only thing you changed, they’re not
> exposed yet, but still.)